# How can I use pandas.apply with args on a sparse dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example:

```
def sum(row,c,d):
    return row['A']+row['B']+c+d

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

The following runs as expected:

```
>>> df.apply(sum,axis=1,args=(9,3))
0     59
1    132
2    138
3    129
4    115
5    113
6     99
7     81
8     80
9    189
```

But converting to a sparse dataframe causes a TypeError:

```
>>> df.to_sparse().apply(sum,axis=1,args=(9,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

I don't see anything in the docs about apply() being handled differently for sparse vs dense dataframes. Is this a bug, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: This feature isn't supported in the API as of yet. One ugly workaround would be using globals with your code.

Comment: Or, use `lambda row: sum(row, 9, 3)` , i.e. use partial application....